# Swap ether to tokens on Uniswap V2 Router 02 fails

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I am trying to buy DAI tokens from my smart contract using ***IUniswapV2Router02***

```
 contract BuyExample{
          
    IUniswapV2Router02 usi = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
       
        /**
         * @param amountOfEther The amount of ether the user has to buy the tokens.
         */
    function buyDai(uint256 amountOfEther) public payable returns(uint256){
    
    address cryptoToken = 0xc7AD46e0b8a400Bb3C915120d284AafbA8fc4735;
    
          uint deadline = now + 15; // I am only using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet I will pass deadline from frontend
            usi.swapETHForExactTokens.value(amountOfEther)(0, getPathForETHToToken(cryptoToken), address(this), deadline);
    
            // refund leftover ETH to user
            msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)("");
    
           return 1000;// a random value for now
        
        }

  function getPathForETHToToken(address crypto) private view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = usi.WETH();
    path[1] = crypto;
    
    return path;
  }

    }
```

The contract deploys successfully.
I try to use it by calling:

```
c.buyDai(web3.utils.toWei('0.02'))
```

...from truffle console.

But it reverts with a long error message.

On kovan.etherscan.io, its status says ***Fail***

What am I doing wrong please?

A running instance of the contract is [here](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x7119e538668f2dc74bb3753ae3d9a7152c1bdbe62a88a89fbff0b220da778bba)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great, it seems you found [my tutorial](https://soliditydeveloper.com/uniswap2). You are mixing up the two different functions of

1. [swapETHForExactTokens](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapethforexacttokens)
2. [swapExactETHForTokens](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapexactethfortokens)

If you want to use the `swapETHForExactTokens`, the first parameter defines how many DAI you want to buy. You are passing along `0`, so it fails. Instead pass the amount of DAI along and make sure to send enough ETH to pay for it. (you may add helper functions to get an ETH estimate, see my tutorial) And you will also need a fallback function to receive refunded ETH.

```
function buyDaiWithExactEth(uint256 amountOfDai) public payable returns(uint256) {
        address cryptoToken = 0xc7AD46e0b8a400Bb3C915120d284AafbA8fc4735;

        uint deadline = now + 15; // I am only using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet I will pass deadline from frontend
        usi.swapETHForExactTokens.value(msg.value)(amountOfDai, getPathForETHToToken(cryptoToken), address(this), deadline);

        // refund leftover ETH to user
        msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)("");

        return 1000; // not sure what this means?
}

receive() payable external {}
```

If you want to use `swapExactETHForTokens`, the first parameter simply defines the minimum amount of DAI that you want. So if you pass `0`, it will always succeeed. You also don't need to refund any ETH, since it's all being used for the purchase.

```
function buyExactDaiWithEth() public payable returns(uint256) {
        address cryptoToken = 0xc7AD46e0b8a400Bb3C915120d284AafbA8fc4735;

        uint deadline = now + 15; // I am only using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet I will pass deadline from frontend
        usi.swapExactETHForTokens.value(msg.value)(0, getPathForETHToToken(cryptoToken), address(this), deadline);

        // no need to refund ETH
        return 1000;
}
```

Comment: I definitely found your tutorial, lol. It was you!
Thanks so much for answering.

Please, in what unit is amountOfDai? 
Is it in dai units or in ether or wei? I want to pass in ether and get Dai out of the system.

Comment: I just tried your exact code(the first one). It still had a status of Failed.
What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Here is the transaction that failed:
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xa42a6def25eeb01ca56888963feb9126cfaa82b610977547ec6e26cd226cddcd

Comment: @gbenroscience You're not sending any ETH along with the transaction. In Remix theres a checkbox in the top left somewhere. In Web3 you have to pass `{ value: amountInEth }` as last transaction parameter. The units are all always in Wei, to get it in DAI/ETH just multiply with `1e18`.

Comment: Oops thanks, can I pass {value: amountInEth} also on truffle console? that's quicker for me to send commands while testing the contract...

I thought:  c.buyDai(web3.utils.toWei('0.02')) would send the required parameters,  anyway.

Comment: I did this:

c.buyDai(1000, {value: 200000000000000000}) and the error changed: See this please:

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x2f9c6dbe5e4ce738d05098262fcedcba3213893e131672cb4c98377853b5b4a6

Comment: @gbenroscience Did you add the fallback function: `receive() payable external {}` ?

Comment: @gbenroscience Actually, I think the error might also be that the token only works for Rinkeby.

Comment: Oops. I will go back to your own token, as used in the blog, then

Comment: Smiling happily. Thanks so much! It worked. The green status has a calming effect dont you think, lol!

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x2708b361843f72bbfea7c606868913f376861063b77e74de9a771d48f13dbccb

Comment: I hope you dont mind me asking, but please I look forward to a blog post on selling tokens on Uniswap V2. Thanks

Comment: @gbenroscience Thanks for the feedback. You mean selling directly with smart contracts right? Check out https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/#swapexacttokensforeth and https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/#swapexacttokensfortokens

Comment: I wrote the sell token functionality, but it has some issues, please can you help me check out the question here:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/swap-tokens-back-to-ether-on-uniswap-v2-router-02-sell-tokens

Comment: Hello guys, do you know how this would work on nodes ? I’m trying to implement swapETHForExactTokens but it doesn’t work

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/109699/66805

Comment: In place of the address of the recipient, why do you place the address(this)? Can I place any other address?

Comment: @AdilNehal Yes you can place any address.