# Swap tokens back to ether on Uniswap V2 Router 02 (Sell tokens)

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I am trying to do the reverse action of what I did in this [**question**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84639/swap-ether-to-tokens-on-uniswap-v2-router-02-fails/84640?noredirect=1#comment105633_84640):
Basically sell/swap some arbitrary token and receive ether on `Uniswap V2` using `IUniswapV2Router02`.

Here is what I have done:

```
 contract SellTokens{
    
       IUniswapV2Router02 usi = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
          
    function sellDai(uint256 daiQty , address cryptoToken) public payable returns(uint256){

//address cryptoToken = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa;//0x00D811B7d33cECCFcb7435F14cCC274a31CE7F5d//multiDaiKovan;

    uint256 ethAmountDerivable = getEstimatedTokenForETH(daiQty , cryptoToken)[0];
 
  uint deadline = now + 300; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!

    usi.swapExactTokensForETH(daiQty , ethAmountDerivable, getPathForTokenToETH(cryptoToken), address(this), deadline);

   return ethAmountDerivable;

}
    
    function getEstimatedTokenForETH(uint daiQty , address crypto) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        return usi.getAmountsIn(daiQty, getPathForTokenToETH(crypto));
      }
    
     function getPathForTokenToETH(address crypto) private view returns (address[] memory) {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = crypto;
        path[1] = usi.WETH();
        
        return path;
      }
    
    }
```

When I call `sellDai` from truffle console using:

```
c.sellDai(web3.utils.toWei('0.02'),'0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa',{value: 3000000000000000})
```

I get the following [**output**](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x0fafe79ce706ef877953944c14549d33e277165d98e1240031830887db5e4011)

The status says:
***Fail with error 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT'***

What could be the issue, please?

**EDIT**

I changed the `getAmountsIn` function call to `getAmountsOut`, and the error changed from `INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT` to `TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED`.

**EDIT 2**

After the admonition to approve the token before transfer, I did this:

```
function sellDai(uint256 daiQty , address cryptoToken) public payable returns(uint256){

//address cryptoToken = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa;//0x00D811B7d33cECCFcb7435F14cCC274a31CE7F5d//multiDaiKovan;

  uint256 ethAmountDerivable = getEstimatedTokenForETH(daiQty , cryptoToken)[0];
  ethAmountDerivable = ethAmountDerivable.mul(10).div(11);// divide by 1.1
 
  uint deadline = now + 300; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!

  IERC20 dai = IERC20(cryptoToken);
  dai.approve(address(this), 0);
  dai.approve(address(this), daiQty);

    usi.swapExactTokensForETH(daiQty , ethAmountDerivable, getPathForTokenToETH(cryptoToken), address(this), deadline);

   return ethAmountDerivable;

}
```

But it still didnt work. Any ideas please. Here is the [transaction](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x4cb8e3f2aae0f073534e3dc67d64a1deadca0ca89e7103570944759a54af4b55)

Thanks again

Comment: If you want help, at least post tidy code.
And if you solve your problem, it would be harmonious to provide the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you are using `getAmountsIn` instead of `getAmountsOut`.
You are starting with the input amount (Dai) and want to get the output amount, not the reverse. It's therefore returning an amount denominated in Dai, which is a much higher number than the equivalent $ value of Eth, so the trade fails the check for the minimum output (which is way too high)
https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/460ffcda51492bef3b191fdaf50092e0d35b66c2/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol#L52

Comment: I changed it to getAmountsOut, now it says:

Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x13a7b0f3a4eca83509baa41077ec7eae3e9f8a290d91c8139cac40d34b00d296

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: I think it's because you haven't called `approve` on the Dai contract that will allow `UniswapV2Router2` to withdraw your Dai and deposit it in to the Dai/Eth pair.
You need to do `dai.approve(address_of_your_contract, large_uint)`
Btw if you're using mainnet or a testnet, you can use https://dashboard.tenderly.co/explorer and it'll show you the code of the error

Comment: I figured as much but I haven't done this before using Uniswap v2 Router02. Can you show a sample that will help with this?

Comment: You can't interact with UniswapV2Router2 to change the allowance amount in the Dai contract, you have to call the Dai contract itself.
You need an ERC20 interface like https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol
and have
```IERC20 dai = IERC20(dai_address);
dai.approve(address(this), amount_to_approve);```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing though, will I do the approval before or after the call to swapExactTokensForEth?

Comment: Definitely before :)

Comment: It still failed with the same error after I added the code to approve. The `dai_address` in IERC20 dai = IERC20(dai_address) , is it same as the `crypto` address passed to the parameter in my example? 

Please see my edit to the question

Comment: Oops, I meant that you should do `approve(address(usi), amount)` not `approve(address(this), amount)`. Anyway, the original question has been answered and I'm basically writing your code for you at this point so could you mark the question as answered please

Comment: Hi, I didnt mark it as answered because all the tests I ran on my code using your suggestions didnt work, so I have no way of knowing if the question is answered or not. Anyway, if you were writing my code for me, you would have provided a working example of how to do the swap in your answer but you didnt. I spent valuable hours  trying to glean out details from you, so dont blame me for not accepting your answer. Anyway, I give you the benefit of the doubt that I am the one not doing something right on my end.

Comment: Your original question was about "Fail with error 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT. What could be the issue, please?'" which I answered and solved, not "I can't made a uniswap trade, please help me get working code" :)
The other error should have been a separate question technically

Comment: Alright thanks for your help, I finally got it working.

Comment: No problem
What was the issue, out of curiosity?

Comment: Here is the working transaction:
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xa920aa944c7a979b54b10fd7c050711c2acd71d1a980372930b27188e59d3d4a

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I debug your issue (which is what you could have easily done yourself):

1. Search `0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D` on https://etherscan.io
2. Click on the `Contract` tab and scroll down to the `Contract Source Code` text box
3. Search for function `swapExactTokensForETH` in the source code
4. Search for `INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT` inside that function
5. Conclude what input parameter may cause the related error

I did some of this work for you.

The contract source code is available [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D#code), and the relevant part of it is:

```
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        virtual
        override
        ensure(deadline)
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        require(path[path.length - 1] == WETH, 'UniswapV2Router: INVALID_PATH');
        amounts = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsOut(factory, amountIn, path);
        require(amounts[amounts.length - 1] >= amountOutMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            path[0], msg.sender, UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amounts[0]
        );
        _swap(amounts, path, address(this));
        IWETH(WETH).withdraw(amounts[amounts.length - 1]);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(to, amounts[amounts.length - 1]);
    }
```

As you may understand, you should reduce the value of `ethAmountDerivable`, which is what you are passing to the function as the input parameter `amountOutMin` (which is designated for your own protection, in case the output amount is smaller than what you define as your minimum limit).

Comment: Wow that's really useful and comprehensive information. Thanks a  lot.

Comment: please check my edit. I checked the contract code and saw where the error message occurred. It has something to do with my contract address, but I cant tell what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code seems the approve function you called before the swap function `swapExactTokensForETH`.

You have approved it for your smart contract address which is wrong, it should be approved for the Uniswap router address: 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D

Let me know if this works.