# swapETHForExactTokens gives ‘EXCESSIVE_INPUT_AMOUNT'

Tags: uniswap

I obtain an error ‘EXCESSIVE_INPUT_AMOUNT’ when performing the swapETHForExactTokens. The uniswapV2 documentation for that function is:

```
function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
  external
  payable
  returns (uint[] memory amounts);
```

I use the code (javascript),

```
 const amountOut = await ethers.utils.parseUnits(`${data.amountOut}`, 'ether');
 
            const tx = await router.swapETHForExactTokens(
                amountOut,
                [tokenIn, tokenOut],
                data.recipient,
                1631312390, //10 minutes
                {
                    'gasLimit': data.gasLimit,
                    'gasPrice': data.gasPriceBuy,

                });
```

where data.amountOut is 10 (10 tokens) and amountOut = ethers.utils.parseUnits(‘data.amountOut’, ‘ethers’) =
10*10**18

I repeatedly obtain the error excessive_input_amount even tough I'm using the right arguments. What might this error be caused by ?